# "Initialize Local Repository" option is missing in local SAP WebIDE

Tags: git, gitlab, sap-web-ide

I am using SAPUI5 local web IDE and facing issue with “Initialize Local Repository”.

Go to your project in SAP WEB IDE, and *right-click* -> *Select Git*, then two options should be there:

1. Clone Repository
2. Initialize Local Repository

But for me, only **Clone Repository** is appearing and **Initialize Local Repository** is not appearing why?

[image]

Please help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: As far as I know this option is only available if there is already a project. If you right-click on the project you can initialize a local repository for it.

Comment: Hi, I already have projects in my webIDE.

Comment: Then right-click on one of your projects and do *Git > Initialize local repository*

Comment: when I do right-click on a project I am not getting this Initialize local repository

Comment: the main question is how did you make your WebIDE **local**? AFAIK, SAP doesn't provide distribution packages for WebIDE

Comment: By "local SAP Web IDE", do you mean "SAP Web IDE Personal Edition"?

Answer (score 0):

Try to update the version of your Web IDE, personal edition.